# SQL. Select all Serial Numbers from two different tables

Tags: sql-server, multiple-columns, multiple-tables

My production is sending items through 1 of 2 identical machines which are logging data to their own tables. Each item has a serial number and I want to list all serial numbers of the parts that have passed the machines.

All tries I have done with Inner Join gives me a result with two columns which I'm not so interested in.

```
CREATE TABLE tblTemp (SerialNumber Varchar(50))
go
INSERT INTO tblTemp SELECT DISTINCT SerialNumber FROM Table1 
go
INSERT INTO tblTemp SELECT DISTINCT SerialNumber FROM Table2
go
SELECT * FROM tblTemp ORDER BY SerialNumber
go
DROP TABLE tblTemp
go
```

My output that I want to have should be like 
   SerialNumber
SN001
SN002
SN003

My code works but I think that there is a way to work with some type of Virtual temporary table so I can have all in one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Union to get all in 1 result.

```
SELECT * FROM
 (SELECT DISTINCT SerialNumber FROM Table1
  UNION
  SELECT DISTINCT SerialNumber FROM Table2 
 ) ORDER BY SerialNumber
```

Comment: That's right. I only added the outer query if you want it sorted after getting all results, but the inner query itself is enough.

Comment: 'SELECT DISTINCT SerialNumber FROM Table1 UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT SerialNumber FROM Table2 ORDER BY SerialNumber'  That did it for me. The initial Select created an error thoug. Thanks for the input!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using union for those two select statements that would help you

Comment: Correct! Simple and easy. Thanks!